# VSCode, Flutter - red underline

Tags: android, dart

Firstly, I was trying to import a project that contains a complete Webview and I was surprised that even after running `flutter clean` ; `flutter pub get` I would still get errors.

I then tried to recreate the demo app following https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab which was working fine at first yesterday. From here I saw that I get the same errors,

Here's my .dart code for the demo app :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Errors]

Sorry for showing the errors by a screenshot but the logs when building are way too long to share, since I think it's a common problem it shouldn't be that troublesome, let me know if you need the errors so I'll do a pastebin.

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found was to delete the Flutter SDK (just delete the folder you downloaded) and to reinstall via git just because I prefer it that way.

I also moved the SDK from C:/Users/my_user/ to C:/src.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you maybe getting some errors while getting the dependencies and flutter is not being downloaded correctly.

If its still happening review your dependencies and do a:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub upgrade
```

If it still happens, review the log of flutter pub get to see what error you maybe getting from the dependencies.

There is another command that could work if your case is that the dependencies are not being updated locally, not on your project, but on your flutter cache. You can use:

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

Comment: Well I tried your commands but it's still showing me the same errors, I tried building the app from Android Studio and it's still the same